# Getting Text property in codebehind from ASP.NET TextBox with TextMode = Password

Tags: asp.net, textbox, passwords, code-behind

I have a `<asp:TextBox` with `TextMode="Password"`. How can I read the value that the user entered, using the codebehind?

I want to create a new user with code like this, but `PasswordTextBox.Text` is always an empty string.

```
Membership.CreateUser(Username, PasswordTextBox.Text)
```

Comment: there has to be more to this. post more code, anything with a reference to `PasswordTextBox`.

Comment: Total guess here, but do you have a Page_Load event handler where you do PasswordTextBox.Text=""? If so, you should only do that when Page.IsPostBack is False (namely, on the first visit to the page and NOT on subsequent postbacks).

Comment: No, I wasn't setting the value anywhere else, but it was on a former WizardStep, and its `.Text` property didn't carry over to the subsequent steps.

Comment: Well, now I feel silly. Should have done a bit more testing before I posted my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there has to be something else going on. I have no problems getting the value in `TextBox.Text`.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. You're probably setting `PasswordTextBox.Text = ''` in the Page_Load(). Don't do that if IsPostback() is true:

```
if not IsPostback() then
    PasswordTextBox.Text = ''
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about reading a password text box.  I'm guessing the problem is somewhere else in your code.  Do you happen to overwrite the values in the Page_Load()?